# ng- select in ng-repeat not working in complex code

Tags: angularjs

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="gridRow in gridData" class="row">
    <select ng-options="room as room.OpRoomName for room in RoomNameList track by room.OpRoomId" ng-model="gridRow.RoomId"></select>
    {{gridRow.RoomId}}
</div>
```

**Data:**

```
 gridData = [{
     A: 2,
     B: 3,
     RoomId: 1
 }, {
     A: 2,
     B: 3,
     RoomId: 3
 }, {
     A: 2,
     B: 3,
     RoomId: 5
 }]

 RoomNameList = [{
     OpRoomName: "A",
     OpRoomId: 1
 }, {
     OpRoomName: "B",
     OpRoomId: 2
 }, {
     OpRoomName: "C",
     OpRoomId: 4
 }, {
     OpRoomName: "D",
     OpRoomId: 3
 }, ]
```

where are not able to set selected option

Comment: {{gridRow.RoomId}} this is for testing only no need of option

Comment: Your Code here is correct.   If you are not able to select a value at all then your problem is not with the code you shared.  [Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ATIcCjAmlqRU2dh7CAAH?p=preview)